# What is `it` in Textfield's onValueChange using Kotlin's Jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I don't know what is `it` in Textfield's onValueChange using Jetpack compose.

```
val usernameState = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())}

TextField(
            value = usernameState.value,
            onValueChange = {usernameState.value = it}
        )
```

Is `it` the argument in lambda function?
I think every time the textfield's value changes, the lambda function is called.
So if we don't use the omission using `it`, what do we write in the lambda function.
Please teach me. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In kotlin you can omit the argument of any lambda, after which you can refer to the argument with `it`

```
onValueChange = {usernameState.value = it}
```

is identical to

```
onValueChange = {value -> usernameState.value = value}
```

This of course only works for lambdas with a single argument.

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer, Ivo. Make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want in the lambda. It is not necessary to update the username state. `It` is just a placeholder for the argument's name. If the `onValueChange` function had 2 parameters you could not use `It`, but something like `Them`, but how would you access each argument `Them.first, Them.second`? nee, it is not pratical so you'll have to specify a name for each argument

```
onMyFunctionCall =  { nameOne, nameWhatever ->  
     state. value = nameOne,
     stateOther.value = nameWhatever
}
```

those arguments `nameOne, nameWhatever` come from the call of a function inside the TextField composable. I can write my own composable like this

```
@Composable
fun CustomUselessComposable(
    text: String,
    myCustomFunction: (text: String, uselessNumber: Int) -> Unit
){
   Text(text, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth() )
   MaterialButton(onClick = {
         myCustomFunction("ciao", 314)
   })
}
```

and then when I use the composable:

```
CustomUselessComposable(
    text = "useless title",
    myCustomFunction = { myText, myNumber -> print(myText+myNumber) }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, zjmo. I will try the those method you taught me.